# I apt-get purged kwalletmanager and now my computer freezes and I can't open anything!

Tags: apt, purge, kwallet

I purged kwalletmanager and now my computer won't open firefox or dolphin. I can't even use apt-get to reinstall kwallet, it just hangs in the terminal. I tried going into the bios after restarting but it just went to a black screen. I'll try to post error messages if I can but does anyone know what has gone wrong and/or how to fix it? I at least need the files off of my computer but it doesn't detect when I plug a flash drive in.

Help!

Comment: I looked and there is a <defunct> kwallet process with a parent called lightdm --session-child 12 19. Killing the parent is not allowed but clearly purging kwallet manager has done something quite catastrophic to my system. I can do things like *top* and *ps ux* but not anything with *apt* or any command requiring *sudo*.

Comment: Okay, I tried opening settings and got the message: KLauncher could not be reached via D-Bus. Error when calling start_service_by_desktop_path: Connection is closed.

Comment: It seems to run okay if I boot it via recovery mode. Regular boot has same problems though.

Answer (score 0):

Boot to recovery mode, [following these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

You can reinstall the `kubuntu-desktop` package to restore KDE, `Kwallet` is part of the desktop package, you should not remove it, there will of been a warning in you terminal when you purged it, telling you what it would remove with it.

In a terminal run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! As you are a new user if this helps you please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to easily find this information

Comment: I wish I could confirm this as the solution. Nothing changed upon following your instructions. I've now been trying to do a fresh install of Kubuntu 14.04 from USB but every time I finish installation I click restart and it hangs. I'm on my third try right now.

Comment: I've tried twice more with no change. Different USBs, same story; it hangs when I get to the end of installation and refuses to restart. Manual restart just brings me back where I was. I open a console and see kwalletd defunct and dbus-daemon defunct. It constantly freezes during startup and refuses to install a fresh OS. I'm super frustrated with this. I just want to burn it down and start over but I can't even do that.